# Top Bar in ViewController ios swift show the previous top bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, navigationitem

First from left.. This is home page. When i click reattempt button will open new viewcontroller which name level page (second from left)

Second from left. This is level page. It show top bar same like home page when run it.

Third from left. This is my storyboard for level page. The top bar show title and back button

Please find the below screenshot for more information.

[image]

My question is why level page not show title and back button like my storyboard when i run.. ? and how to make level page show title and back button ?

I already embed in navigation controller .. Please help me..

Comment: Have you shown this screen using Storyboard segue Or Do you have any action method to show that screen.

Comment: i used this code to call the level page.. self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

Comment: Have you connected Segue from Job List controller to Level Controller?

Comment: are you using xib's? have you set up your constraints properly?

Comment: As i can see you are pushing your Level Controller.. on your navigation controller so that level controller is taking basic behaviour of your navigationcontroller. If you will connect a segue from joblist to level controller that it will show the same screen. (second one)

Comment: From joblist , i used that code to open level controller .. in storyboard i have storyboard entry point -> navigation controller then have relationship "root view controller to level controller"

Comment: inseed of pushing... try  self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true)

Comment: i set up my constraints properly

Comment: if i used self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true) , it show nothing.. no top bar like joblist and no top bar like my storyboard

Comment: yes because your presenting viewcontroller is not having any navigation controller

Comment: Do these steps: Drag and drop a NavigationController in story board remove its defaulf tableviewcontroller from it. Embade you level contoller into that. Assign a identifier to your new navigation controller and instantiate that navigation controller and do self.presentViewController(navcontroller, animated: true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let navController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YouNewNavigationControllerIdentifier") as! UINavigationController
self.presentViewController(navController, animated: true)
```

Hope this will work...!!

Comment: it show nothing.. no top bar like joblist and no top bar like my storyboard

Comment: Do these steps: Drag and drop a NavigationController in story board remove its defaulf tableviewcontroller from it. Embade you level contoller into that. Assign a storyboard identifier to your new navigation controller and instantiate that navigation controller and do self.presentViewController(navcontroller, animated: true) –

Comment: when i embad my level controller so i got two navigation controller ? one i drag , other one i embed  right ?

Comment: Another one is tableviewcontroller... you have to delete that tableview controller only.... not navigation controller

Comment: After removing that.. drag pointer from navigation controller to your level controller and make it as a rootview controller

Comment: According to your requirement suggest you that... So that your levelview controller will not have basic behavior of your first navigation controller

Comment: See there are two things and both depends on your requirement. If you could share more about your screen transitions then i could help you more precisely.

Comment: i cant add more picture to show .. just can add one picture .. i still new in stackoverflow

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong... i could help you using skype... if you want

Comment: Welcome.. :) if your issue resolve so could you mark it as a answer.

Comment: owh .. sorry .. i click up arrow before this .. overlooked .. now i click right .. thank a lot man